# Best way to collect data from multiple components into one in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I create a form in several steps. Here is my tree :

- fullForm.vue

  - firstStep.vue
  - secondStep.vue
  - thirdStep.vue

Each step has several fields that are stored in data().

// example for step 1

```
 data: () => ({
      model: {
        official_name: '',
        commmercial_name: '',
        status: '',
        status_other: '',
        …
```

Each step is an import component in parent component (fullForm.vue)

```
    <first-step ref="firstStep" @on-validate="onStepValidate"></first-step>
    <second-step ref="secondStep" @on-validate="onStepValidate"></second-step>
    <third-step ref="thirdStep" @on-validate="onStepValidate"></third-step>
```

I would like to combine the data of all my child components in my data `formFull` in `fullForm.vue`.

I tried this :

```
onStepValidate(validated, model) {
   if (validated) {
     this.formFull = { ...this.formFulll, ...model };
    }
 }
```

It works halfway.

When I complete step one and valid, `formFull` fills up with step 1.

When I validate step 2, it erases `formFull` and fills it only with step 2.

How to keep all the data? Thanks !

Comment: Try to use global observable API like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710800/why-i-can-use-vuex/57712105#57712105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo (3 ls):

```
this.formFull = { ...this.formFulll, ...model };
```

Try this:

```
this.formFull = { ...this.formFull, ...model };
```