# Listen to event in VueJS parent component to call a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

My VueJS 2 application contains a parent component and a child component. The parent passes a prop called `items` to the child.

When the user clicks on a button in the child component it emits a `refresh` event like this:

```
$emit('refresh', category.id)
```

I'd like to listen to this event in the parent component and, if the event is received, trigger a method, e.g. `alert()`.

As far as I have understood the [``](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) the `v-on` listener can be attached to e.g. a button or else. The problem is that my parent component does not have something like a button for this.

To make things clearer here's what I'm thinking of:

1. Parent component is loaded. It calls a `getData()` function which result is passed as a prop to the child component.
2. The user clicks a button in the child component.
3. The child component triggers an event.
4. The parent component again calls `getData()` and updated the prop passed to the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assuming that you have in child component a code like  :

```
  <button v-on:click="$emit('refresh', category.id)" ...
```

in the parent one you should have this

```
                     <child v-on:refresh="refreshParent"   />
 event emitted from child  ---------^       ^-------- its handler method in the parent
```

in the parent methods :

```
  methods:{
    refreshParent(idCateg){
        this.getData()
     }
  ....
  }
```

Comment: Ah, I can see my problem now. Your code works fine. In my case I missed to see that the `$emit` is called from another component, i.e. my parent component didn't receive it because it actually is the "grandparent" component.

Comment: if you have a complicated situation where you have to share the same data between component i recommend to use  Observable API like it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710800/why-i-can-use-vuex/57712105#57712105)

Comment: Had a well-hidden typo in my code. Your suggestion works fine :-)

Answer (score 2):

you don't actually need a button for that purpose. I'll try to show you the code

ParentComponent.vue:

```
<child-comp @refresh="refreshFunc" />


methods: {
  refreshFunc (categoryId) {
    // here you go
  }
}
```

ChildComponent.vue:

```
  this.$emit('refresh', categoryId)
```

Comment: Your answer is almost identical to the one I've chosen. Thanks for your help.