# How to reuse data obtained by axios calls between VueJS components?

Tags: vue.js, components, axios, reusability

I am sorry if this question has already been asked, but i can't seem to find a **clear** explanation for my problem.

Problem: i have a web page showing a client's problem. This page need data like client ID or problem number to display it in different parts of the page (header, menu, body). This data is obtained with axios calls.

So i have multiple components which need the same data from the same axios call.

I can't understand how it is possible to make **one** axios call, for client ID for example, and share it with multiple components instead of making an axios call **each time** i need the data.

Are mixins a solution?

I have tried to use a mixin:

```
Vue.axiosGet({
    methods: {
        request: function(url) {
            return axios.get(url).then(response => {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But now i don't know where or how to store the data i'll get.

EDIT: i forgot to precise that i don't want to use VueX.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710800/why-i-can-use-vuex/57712105#57712105

Comment: you can always cache axios calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you don't want to use Vuex, but why not? I would recommend you use the Vuex store to achieve what you're looking for. A vuex store will cache/hold information in it, meaning that you can easily access it on a different page. Vuex would solve your problem and allow you make a call once, and later access the data. No need to re-invent the wheel, it's an effective way to achieve what you need.

Comment: I didn't want to because i thought it was possible to achieve with only VueJS... But almost every solution i found mention VueX. So you're right maybe i should use it, i will try to understand it.

Comment: It'll make your life easier. You could store it in localStorage, but Vuex is set up exactly for what you want to achieve. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't wanna use Vuex, there're always solutions like [nedb](https://dbdb.io/db/nedb), but I'd strongly recommend Vuex.